# insert video in video ffmpeg at time exact

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I have Video out.mp4 have 30 sec I want to put new video image1.mp4 have 5 sec in   out.mp4 at 10 seconds
i have this code to put my image1.mp4 in out.mp4

```
ffmpeg -i F:\out.mp4  -vf "movie=image2.mp4 , scale=200:-1,fade=out:200:alpha=1 , [inner]; [in][inner] overlay=70:70 [out]"  -c:v libx264  -s "1080x720" completed.mp4
```

the output

```
    >ffmpeg -i F:\out.mp4 -vf "movie=image2.mp4 , scale=200:-1,fade=out:100:alpha=1
 [inner]; [in][inner] overlay=70:70 [out]"  completed.mp4
ffmpeg version N-70411-g7da7d26 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-lib
modplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrw
b --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinge
r --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --en
able-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis
 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-
libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enab
le-zlib
  libavutil      54. 19.100 / 54. 19.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 24.101 / 56. 24.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'F:\out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.24.101
  Duration: 00:00:16.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 309 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 800x640 [
SAR 1:1 DAR 5:4], 306 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
[swscaler @ 0000000005608ea0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did se
t range correctly
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] 264 - core 144 r2525 40bb568 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 deci
mate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_
adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=2
5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.6
0 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'completed.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.24.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 8
00x640 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:4], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   68 fps=0.0 q=29.0 size=      96kB time=00:00:00.63 bitrate=1245.6kbits/
frame=  111 fps=107 q=29.0 size=     161kB time=00:00:02.06 bitrate= 637.5kbits/
frame=  155 fps=100 q=29.0 size=     222kB time=00:00:03.53 bitrate= 514.3kbits/
frame=  212 fps=103 q=29.0 size=     270kB time=00:00:05.43 bitrate= 406.5kbits/
frame=  270 fps=105 q=29.0 size=     292kB time=00:00:07.36 bitrate= 324.9kbits/
frame=  314 fps=102 q=29.0 size=     465kB time=00:00:08.83 bitrate= 431.6kbits/
frame=  382 fps=106 q=29.0 size=     569kB time=00:00:11.10 bitrate= 420.0kbits/
frame=  461 fps=112 q=29.0 size=     597kB time=00:00:13.73 bitrate= 356.2kbits/
frame=  500 fps=107 q=-1.0 Lsize=     629kB time=00:00:16.60 bitrate= 310.3kbits
/s
video:623kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing o
verhead: 0.984177%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] frame I:3     Avg QP:15.65  size: 90538
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] frame P:190   Avg QP:21.18  size:  1663
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] frame B:307   Avg QP:30.53  size:   161
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] consecutive B-frames: 18.0%  0.0%  1.2% 80.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] mb I  I16..4: 17.4% 72.4% 10.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.3%  0.2%  P16..4:  5.0%  1.3
%  0.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:92.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  2.1%  0.3
%  0.1%  direct: 0.1%  skip:97.4%  L0:39.2% L1:52.6% BI: 8.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] 8x8 transform intra:68.7% inter:65.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 79.0% 49.6% 23.6% inter: 1
.1% 1.6% 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 92%  5%  1%  2%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19%  8% 22%  7%  8%
12%  5% 13%  6%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 18% 16%  5%  6%
 8%  6%  7%  6%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 63% 16% 18%  3%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] ref P L0: 59.0% 18.1% 17.1%  5.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] ref B L0: 83.8% 11.7%  4.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] ref B L1: 96.5%  3.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000002c1c3a0] kb/s:305.76
```

Comment: You need to include the complete console output from your command.

Comment: Run the command. Once it finishes copy the output and paste it into your question.

Comment: ok i put the output console :)

Comment: There is a between option wonder if that would help http://stackoverflow.com/a/29222419/32453 (and select filter?) dunno...

Comment: thankyou but i d'ont no how i can do its ffmpeg -i F:\out.mp4 -vf "movie=image2.mp4 , scale=200:-1,fade=out:100:alpha=1 ,select=between(t\,4\,9) [inner]; [in][inner] overlay=70:70 [out]"  completed.mp4 but its selected from image2.mp4 not for the input video out.mp4 how i can apply this for input ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to split your original video and concat the three parts.

As we can evince from the ffmpeg-user mailing list, there's no current filter to help "insert" ops...

Quoting an August 2014 discussion:

> > To whom it may be concerned:
> >
> > Hi,
> >     I'm a user of ffmpeg. I know ffmpeg can concat two videos or audios into a
> >     new single media file, but I want to insert a video or audio into the
> >     middle of the media file,for example, the duration of "a.avi " is 00:05:00,
> >     and the duration of "b.rmvb " is 00:01:00, I want to insert "b.rmvb" into
> >     the postion "00:02:00" of a.avi, the duration of new a.avi is
> >     "00:06:00",how to fulfill it? if not, can you add this new function into
> >     ffmpeg and update it?
> >      thanks for your attention.
>
> Yes it can, but you would need to split the first video into 2 videos and
>   then concat all 3. That is how an insert works (even in a NLE program like
>   Avid, FCP or Premiere).
>
> Note that all the formats need to be identical and you would need to either
>   use an intra frame edit friendly format or split on an I frame
>
> ---
>
> ffmpeg-user mailing list
>   ffmpeg-user at ffmpeg.org
>   http://ffmpeg.org/mailman/listinfo/ffmpeg-user

Comment: Tks for your post how i can my video and concat again ?

Comment: @Ryodo you can find a lot of tutorials, here's a link with a bunch of usefull commands (split and join too) http://www.labnol.org/internet/useful-ffmpeg-commands/28490/