# Silence (zero out) parts of an audio file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox

I want to silence parts of an audio file (position varies) using some command line tool (ffmpeg, sox, ...) but can't find out how.

I found `sox ... pad` to be the closest to what I want but it's still not it, I need to **override** the audio not add to it (pad).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29222419/1806873). You can mute certain parts of an audio file using ffmpeg with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -af "volume=enable='between(t,5,10)':volume=0, volume=enable='between(t,15,20)':volume=0" ...
```

Comment: I want to pass a list of [[start, end ]] time stamps so that those portions are silenced out. what would be best way to achieve this using sox or ffmpeg? i.e