# ffmpeg remove a part of audio in mp4 file but not all

Tags: video, replace, ffmpeg

i got an mp4 and i want to remove 3 minutes of sound on 4h video (to upload on youtube).

i try : `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c copy -an video-sansson.mp4`

the full audio is deleted.

I personally just want to remove 3 minutes of it ?

Comment: Remove 3 minutes from the end, beginning, middle, or arbitrary segments? Do you want to remove the video to? Or do you just want to mute the audio?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mute specified sections of an audio file using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215197/mute-specified-sections-of-an-audio-file-using-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this should work:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -af "volume=enable='between(t,5,10)':volume=0" -c:v copy video-sansson.mp4
```

this applies a volume filter between 5 and 10 seconds - obviously you'll want to adjust that